# Problema en escritura de ficheros en Java (borrado de un elemento de un JList)

Tags: java, lista, filewriter

No soy capaz de escribir en el archivo. Ya escribo varias veces en él, aquí solamente estoy actualizando la lista después de seleccionar un elemento de JList (lo borro). Le he pasado el depurador y llega a la instrucción de escritura respetando correctamente el continue. El problema es que no escribe. No quiero sobreescribir el archivo, mi array "elementos" contiene ya todos los elementos que deben escribirse (incluido el seleccionado, el cual quitamos con la condicion).
Cuando cierro y abro mi programa después de haber pasado por este código, aunque tenga más elementos en mi lista, desaparecen, y del archivo de entrada, también, pero eso es por no poner el parámetro true al FileWriter.
Estoy seguro de que es un detalle que no estoy teniendo en cuenta, pero no lo veo. Es necesario que meta lo que hay dentro de la variable elementos, ya que hay más datos que en cualquiera de las otras variables.

```
FileWriter rr;
            try {
                rr = new FileWriter(dir);
                BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(rr);
                String aux=list_1.getSelectedItem();
                String[] sp=aux.split(" ");
                for(int i=0;i<elementos.length;i++) {
                    String[] auxi=elementos[i].split(" ");
                    if(auxi[0].equals(sp[0]) && auxi[1].equals(sp[1]) && auxi[2].equals(sp[2])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    br.write(elementos[i]);

                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Para escribir a un archivo de texto plano, puedes usar este ejemplo:

```
public void escribirArchivo(Path rutaDestino, List<String> lineas) {

    try {
         if(Files.exists(rutaDestino)){ // Si el archivo ya existe. escribe al final
                Files.write(rutaDestino, lineas, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
         }else{ //Sino existe, lo crea y escribe todo el archivo
               Files.write(rutaDestino, lineas, Charset.forName("UTF-8"), StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
         }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}
```